# Angular 4 datepicker styling

Tags: javascript, css, angular, datepicker

I'm trying to insert a datepicker in my angular 4 app but I've faced some dificulties.

So I tried this [kekeh/mydaterangepicker](https://github.com/kekeh/mydaterangepicker) but I need to have this design:

[image]

I tried to modify the css of the plugin in my css but without real success. I cant succed to change the color of first selected node and last selected node to follow my design.

My actual state:

[image]

If someone can help me.

I can also start from scratch but I don't know how to properly create a datepicker in angular.

Comment: To get more people to help you with this kind of question use codepen/jsfiddle to mock up your problem!

Comment: I'd suggest Kendo UI for Angular datepicker. They provide a lot of ability for customization. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/#toc-calendar-templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles of the component can be changed by overriding the existing styles.

Read [documentation](https://github.com/kekeh/mydaterangepicker) and follow the instructions. The library documentation also provides you with examples.

Also you you might want to use [Angular material datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)
It is very convinient to work with it and it has bunch of other useful components.

Comment: Thx you this guide me to this https://ipiz.herokuapp.com/md-date-range-picker-demo/index.html witch is what I need nearly